# Correct usage: fields of A and B vs fields of A and of B?

Tags: grammatical-number

I am writing about a scientific article which treats a question on the borderline between two distinctly different research areas, A and B. I need a phrase saying  "The work belongs to the field of A and to the field of B", but I do not like the repetition of the word "field". Which of the variants below is correct?

1. The work belongs to the fields of A and of B.
2. The work belongs to the fields of A and B.
3. The work belongs to the field of A and B.
4. The work belongs to the field of A and of B.

Comment: It's a stylistic issue to some degree, but I'd favor #2.  (Though I'm not sure I'd use "The work belongs" in the scenario you describe. Maybe "straddles" or some such -- in which case it would be "The work straddles the fields A and B.")

Comment: I agree. Other words for "straddles" might be "spans", "bridges" or "combines aspects of".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least convoluted sense of the phrase in option 3 is that A and B together form a single field: "the field of A and B." So if that isn't the meaning you intend to convey, option 3 is not a good choice.

Option 4 fairly strongly implies "the field of A and [the field] of B, but the wording sounds a bit herky-jerky to me, even though it does smooth out when I (as a reader) add the implied second instance of "the field" in the appropriate place. But if I (as a writer) require my readers to back-fill "the field" for me in order to make the sentence read smoothly, then neither they nor I have gained anything positive from the shorter wording that we wouldn't have had if I had simply made those words explicit in the first place.

Option 1 is actually a bit more problematic than option 4 because the implied words in that case are "fields of," as in "The work belongs to the fields of A and [the fields] of B." Since (presumably) you don't mean to say that A comprises multiple fields and so does B, the wording doesn't point readers in the right direction.

That leaves, of the four options you provide, option 2 ("The work belongs to the fields of A and B"), which reads smoothly and makes sense at the simplest level of interpretation—namely, that "the fields of A and B" means "field A and field B."

So I would choose either option 2 or a simplified version the original wording (the wording that you want to avoid): "The work belongs to field A and to field B."

Answer (score 0):

Since your primary requirement is that you don't want to repeat `field`, try

> The work belongs to the field of A and that of B.